# Run parse aftersave cloud code only on certain attributes

Tags: parse-platform

I set up the parse cloud code and its working great. I am looking for a way to run aftersave cloud code only if certain attributes are modified. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do exactly, but you may use [dirty](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.Object.html#dirty) or [dirtyKeys](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.Object.html#dirtyKeys) to check if your attributes are modified in `beforeSave`.

In `afterSave` [existed](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.Object.html#existed) can be useful too to check if the object is just created or already existed.

Example for `dirty`:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Location", function(request, response) {
  var location = request.object;

  if (location.dirty("photo")) {
    // photo is modified
    // do something (like resizing the photo as thumbnail)
  } 

  response.success();
  return;
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to recognize if certain attributes are changed in the previous save. Not after the previous save happened.

Comment: This is the current save. As the name suggests, this function is called before the save happens. So you can stop the save or modify the objects before it saves. Say that this save has attributes that are changed. You can check and keep a column (indicating the changed attributes) for the next save.

Comment: oh... well, i got your point.  Basically am trying to shoot a mail based on the attributes modified. I can run the cloud code as beforesave and if the attributes am looking for are dirty then shoot a mail. This way i can choose different mail formats based on which attributes are dirty. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi @Knshn... i am also working on cloud code. can you please tell me, "photo" mentioned in the above code is your column name?

Comment: Yes it is an arbitrary column name.

Answer (score 1):

My way:

Create a "dummy" column (not used in your app), named: changedcolumns

in beforeSave check each field, if it is dirty then put the changed field name to the changedcolumns field, like "name,date,gender"

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
        var changedColumns=",";
        if (request.object.dirty("locale")) {
            changedColumns=changedColumns+"locale,"
        }
        ....other columns....

        request.object.set("changedColumns",changedColumns);
        
        ....
        
});
```

in the afterSave you have a column with the changed column names (you can check it with indexOf function)

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
        var changedColumns=request.object.get("changedColumns");
        if (changedColumns==null) {
            changedColumns="";
        }
        if (changedColumns.indexOf(",locale,")>-1) {    //locale changed
            ... LOCALE CHANGED ...
            ... DO SOMETHING ...
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. There is no such filter specified on the function. You can't differentiate first save / update in the function spec either. You will need to add logic inside the function to determine if it has any work to do.

Comment: Thanks for conforming. I added a **shootMail** boolean attribute to the table. In cloudcode if *shootMail == true;* i shoot out the mail and put *shootMail = false* and save. From the client code, only when i change the attributes for which i Intended to shoot out the mail i put it back to true. Cheers.

Comment: To parse super users out there... Won't it be super helpful if we can link aftersave to specific attributes instead of the whole class ?